# How to use PyQt5 Multi-threading?

Tags: pyqt5

I know this question has been answered before, but I can't understand from those examples.
There is a file called in the backend which executes functions.

This is my code:

```
def execGenion(self):
        #if self.CN_exec_pushButton.clicked == True:
        subprocess.check_call([path,"genion","-s",cntprf,"-o",cnoutf,"-p",cntopof,"-pname",posi,"-nname",negi,"-neutral"])

#Button for this function -
self.CN_exec_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.execGenion)
```

Now when this button is pressed on the GUI the control is transferred to the backend file where it asks for another input. But the GUI freezes and I can't give the next input. How do I fix this?

I tried using the examples on RealPython and certain different platforms but couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: As the [`check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) documentation says, it will "**wait for command to complete**". Either use `Popen` or QProcess. Also, please learn how to properly [format code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) in your posts.

Comment: I used subprocess.Popen to connect to the backend file. Also tried it using QApplication.processEvents().

Comment: Then show us what you tried.